# google maps mysql query to find bus

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I'm working on a project for a bus consulting service using google maps. You drag an icon to the place you are and where you want to go, and the app will tell what bus to take, this is working right now, but I want to make bus combinations to get to a place if no direct bus.

I have all the buses routes of my city into a database with lat/lng:

```
id  |  bus_id   |    lat   |   lng
-------------------------------------
1   |  12       |  -23.232 |  23.328
2   |  12       |  -23.233 |  23.327
3   |  12       |  -23.234 |  23.326
4   |  12       |  -23.235 |  23.325
```

My query for finding nearest buses to an origin an destination lat/lng is this:

```
SELECT 
    id, number
    FROM buses
    WHERE id IN
    (
        SELECT bus_id 
        FROM coord 
        WHERE 
        POW((lat - '.$points["direction"]["lat"].'), 2) + POW((lng - '.$points["direction"]["lng"].'), 2) < POW(('.$distance.' / 111.12), 2)
    )
    AND id IN
    (
        SELECT bus_id
        FROM coord 
        WHERE 
        POW((lat - '.$points["person"]["lat"].'), 2) + POW((lng - '.$points["person"]["lng"].'), 2) < POW(('.$distance.' / 111.12), 2)
    )
```

How could I check for bus combinations when theres no direct bus for that origin/destination points?

Thanks!!

BTW checkit out: http://www.mapabondi.com.ar/
Spanish only, sorry! (feedback appreciated)

**EDIT:**

I came up with a query that finds out bus combinations

```
SELECT
    o.bus_id,
    d.bus_id,
    o.lat,
    o.lng,
    d.lat,
    d.lng,
    ROUND(GeoDistKM(o.lat,o.lng,d.lat,d.lng)) AS distance
FROM coord o
JOIN coord d
WHERE o.bus_id IN (
    SELECT bus_id 
    FROM coord 
    WHERE 
    POW((lat - -31.528361), 2) + POW((lng - -68.583527), 2) < POW((1 / 111.12), 2)
    )
AND d.bus_id IN (
    SELECT bus_id 
    FROM coord 
    WHERE 
    POW((lat - -31.571516), 2) + POW((lng - -68.521385), 2) < POW((1 / 111.12), 2)
    )
GROUP BY d.bus_id,o.bus_id
HAVING distance < 1
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

My only problem right now is with performance, this query is very slow... Any chance it could get better with a stored procedure or function?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer really but maybe something to get you started.

I think you should consider adding a new table bus_stops

```
bus_id bus_stop_name lat        lon
12     stadium       -23.145    23.315
12     halembra      -23.234    23.326
...
14     halembra      -23.234    23.326
14     dali          -23.242    23.345
```

Then, finding a correspondance will be easier:

- find start and stop nearest bus stops by euclidian distance
- find a path of shared bus stops using the bus_stops table

  - this problem is formalized in Graph Theory and is called graph traversal, see [this google query](http://www.google.fr/search?q=graph%20traversal%20in%20sql) for information and sample code.

Not easy though! good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Laurent', a friend of mine suggested that I could: 1) Find all buses near start point 2) Find all buses near end point 3) Some how find out wich buses from that two lists haver points near between them.
Any ideas if this could be this possible in one query or two?

Comment: Your problem is one of the oldest of information theory. It's called 'graph traversal' and can require many iterations. Google it with with sql keyword, you'll find many examples. Now, you may prefer to find solutions with one change only, this is much easier.